# Using regular expression in Ext Js VType

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, extjs

I have a regular expression for checking numbers and allowing "-" (Hyphen) Text Field.

```
var regex = /^\d+-\d{1,2}$/;  //Checks "digits-digit(s,1 or 2)"
```

This works ok for regular HTML text field. But if I want a Ext Js TextField I have to do the below code

Ext js TextField and called a VType

```
var <portlet:namespace/>issueNoField = new Ext.form.TextField({
     fieldLabel: 'Issue No',
     width: 120,
     valueField:'IssNo',
     vtype: 'hyphen'
 });

Ext.apply(Ext.form.VTypes, {
                hyphenText : "Only numbers and hyphen.",
                hyphenMask:/[0-9-]/,
                hyphenRe: /^\d+-\d{1,2}$/,  //This is the check
                hyphen:function(x){return this.hyphenRe.test(x);}   //Am i missing a numericHyMask: here ??
            });     

      Is hyphenRe: /^\d+-\d{1,2}$/, is correct or
      is hyphenRe: /^\d+-[\d{1,2}]$/, is correct as I want 1 or 2 digits after '-'
```

Please help me change my VTypes to work properly and do that regex check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me. Is the validation itself not working (the field doesn't get underlined when you type invalid stuff in it) or are you missing the error-tooltip? On the latter case add somewhere in your code:

```
Ext.QuickTips.init();
```

Otherwise the tooltips wont appear.

Comment: I edited my script above, please suggest. I am using QuickTips above my script.

Comment: I tested your code, and it worked just fine. Except for the `<portlet:namespace/>` which I left out. The field nicely validates against your regex. But I see that now you have added an incorrect regex `/^\d+-[\d{1,2}]$/`. Are you having a problem with writing regular expressions? In that case, explain in more detail what you really want that regex to mach.