# What does /i at the end of a regex mean?

Tags: javascript, regex, time, expression

What is the meaning of `/i` at the tail of this regex?

```
var time = /^([1-9]|1[0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(\s[a|p]m)$/i;
```

Comment: Note that `[a|p]` matches `a`, `|` or `p` (yes, the `|` as well!). Inside a character set, the pipe has no special meaning. So you'll probably want to do: `[ap]m` which matches `am` or `pm`.

Comment: Also, you first part `([1-9]|1[0-9])` will only match `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, ... , `'19'`. Is that correct?

Comment: @Bart: Thanks. Now if I want `digits-digits` i.e `xxxx-xx` i.e n digits n then `-` and then one or two digits, my regex will look like this?
`/^\d+-\d{1,2}$/` or  something else?

Comment: @Bart: I need your input here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966520/using-regular-expression-in-ext-js-vtype/4967137#4967137)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

`/i` stands for ignore case in the given string. Usually referred to as case-insensitive as pointed out in the comment.

Comment: usually referred to as case-insensitive

Comment: @oneofthelions: Full syntax is readily available in the spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm And there *might* be the odd website or two providing JavaScript regular expressions info in more accessible language.

Comment: @Piskvor - yes, thanks. I totally forgot that word and had type incase-sensitive..:) Have edited my answer for this.

Answer (score 9):

It's, like Sachin Shanbhag already answered the 'ignore case' modifier. So `/[a-z]/i` is equal to `/[a-zA-Z]/`. Check [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) for other modifiers.