# Pardot form validation regex

Tags: pardot

I've created a custom form field for Canadian Postal code. Is there a way i can validate the format using RegEx? I can make it required, but I need more than that.

Comment: I'm seeing 27,300 results when Googling `Canadian postcode regex`. Always remember to do that first. Does none of the results work for you? If that's the case, consider adding more detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient regex for Canadian postal code function]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774555/efficient-regex-for-canadian-postal-code-function)

Comment: Pekka, do you know what Pardot is?

Comment: No, I assumed that is what Canadian postal codes are named in French or something, and you were tagging incompetently. Apologies. (The regexes in the linked questions might still be helpful, depending on what notation the product uses, no?)