# regex to extract postal code from an address

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a list of addresses have merged postal codes shown below

```
65 Windermere Ave., Toronto, ON, M6S 3J4
15 Bruyeres Mews, Toronto, ON M5V 0G8, Canada
M6M1N7, Canada
437 revus Ave, L5G 1S2, Mississauga, ON
, ST. CATHARINES L2M 6Z2 ON
15 Viking Lane, Toronto M9B0A4 ON
```

I tried this regex to extract postal code but got no output

```
^.{3}(?:[\s]).{3}^$
```

**Update**

postal codes examples: M6S 3J4,L5G 1S2,M9B0A4

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46761018/9758194) be helpfull?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this regex `(([A-Z]\d[A-Z])+\s?\d[A-Z]\d)` that will find all the upper case letter follows by digit and other upper case letter and then it checks if there is a space followed by digit upper case letter and another digit.

```
import re

txt = """
65 Windermere Ave., Toronto, ON, M6S 3J4
15 Bruyeres Mews, Toronto, ON M5V 0G8, Canada
M6M1N7, Canada
437 revus Ave, L5G 1S2, Mississauga, ON
, ST. CATHARINES L2M 6Z2 ON
15 Viking Lane, Toronto M9B0A4 ON
"""

print([i[0] for i in re.findall(r"(([A-Z]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1})+\s?(\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1})*)", txt)])
```

Output

```
['M6S 3J4', 'M5V 0G8', 'M6M1N7', 'L5G 1S2', 'L2M 6Z2', 'M9B0A4']
```

Comment: `{1}` is unnecessary

Comment: @anubhava Thanks I removed the `{1}` from the regex.

Answer (score 3):

[Canadian postal codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_codes_in_Canada) take the format `A1A 1A1` where `A` is a letter and `1` is a digit. You're better off matching that explicitly in your regex.

A working regex would look like this:

```
[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\s?\d[A-Z]\d
```

A few things to note:

- Your current regex is anchoring the match which you don't want to do in this case
- You will want to use `re.search` and not `re.match`, since `re.match` [anchors the match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match)
- Make the `\s` optional using `?` (which means zero or one occurrences)

Here's a working example:

```
lines = '''65 Windermere Ave., Toronto, ON, M6S 3J4
15 Bruyeres Mews, Toronto, ON M5V 0G8, Canada
M6M1N7, Canada
437 revus Ave, L5G 1S2, Mississauga, ON
, ST. CATHARINES L2M 6Z2 ON
15 Viking Lane, Toronto M9B0A4 ON'''

import re

for s in lines.split('\n'):
    m = re.search(r'([A-Z]\d[A-Z]\s?\d[A-Z]\d)', s)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Output:

```
M6S 3J4
M5V 0G8
M6M1N7
L5G 1S2
L2M 6Z2
M9B0A4
```

If you want a fully general solution for matching postal codes from around the world, then check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578406/what-is-the-ultimate-postal-code-and-zip-regex).