# Checking input in javascript to see if it matches a Canadian postal code

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a form for getting information about the user in html and javascript and I am struggling to check if one of my text box inputs is in a specific format.

The format is: `### ###`

Where each `#` is either a letter or a number, an example of this would be `N3H 2E9`.

My input is from a regular html text box that is being converted into a const within my javascript and I'm wondering if there is a way to validate that the input is in the same format as previously mentioned. I'm pretty new to html and javascript so if you answer please could you provide a small explanation behind your answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774555/efficient-regex-for-canadian-postal-code-function

Comment: The link that @Ry gave uses better regexes than the answers below, because not _all_ letters A-Z are allowed in a Canadian postal code. Also, don't forget that you can use `<input type="text" pattern="regex"...>` for the browser to validate the field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regular Expressions (RegEx)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) to do what you want.

```js
const correctInput = "N3H 2E9";
const incorrectInput = "N3H 2Ea";

const isValid = (input) => /^[0-9A-Z]{3} [0-9A-Z]{3}$/.test(input);

console.log(isValid(correctInput));
console.log(isValid(incorrectInput));
```

```
/^[0-9A-Z]{3} [0-9A-Z]{3}$/
```

- `^`: Matches start of the string
- `[0-9A-Z]{3}`: Matches exactly three characters which are one of uppercase A-Z or digits 0-9
- : Matches space
- `$`: Matches end of the string

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validateForm() {
  var postalCode = document.getElementById("postal_code").value;
  // This solution uses a regular expression to test the input for our desired format
  // for more info on what this pattern means exactly, check out
  // https://regex101.com/?regex=^[A-Z0-9]{3}%20[A-Z0-9]{3}$
  var rgx = /^[A-Z0-9]{3} [A-Z0-9]{3}$/;
  var isValid = rgx.test(postalCode);
  var resultElement = document.getElementById("result");
  if (isValid) {
    resultElement.innerText = "Valid"
  } else {
    resultElement.innerText = "Invalid"
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="postal_code">
<button onclick="validateForm()">Validate</button>
<span id="result">Invalid</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most easily accomplished using a *regular expression*.
A regular expression defines a pattern of characters that input can be tested against. In javascript you can create one as follows:

```
const expression = /test/
```

`expression` is now a regular expression and you can use it to validate strings (in this case, testing whether a part of it contains `"test"`):

```
expression.test("Hello") // false
expression.test("test") // true
expression.test("Hello this is a test") // true
expression.test("Hey I'm testing") // true
expression.test("t est") // false
expression.test("Test") // false
```

Regular expressions can contain special selectors that define not a literal string (`"test"` for example) but a range of allowed characters. In your example you want to test against numbers and capital letters. That can be notated as `[A-Z0-9]` meaning *"any character between A and Z or between 0 and 9"*. You want three of those, which can be notated as `[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]` or simply as `[A-Z0-9]{3}`. The final expression would look like:

```
const expression = /^[A-Z0-9]{3} [A-Z0-9]{3}$/
```

Note the special characters `^` and `$`. They correspond with the *beginning* and *ending* of a string, ensuring you're not matching any string merely containing a postal code, but only strings exclusively containing a postal code.

Finally, you could write this function as follows:

```
const isCanadianPostalCode = input => /^[A-Z0-9]{3} [A-Z0-9]{3}$/.test(input);

console.log( isCanadianPostalCode('N3H 2E9A') ) // false
console.log( isCanadianPostalCode('N3H 2E9') ) // true
```