# How to optimise following Regex to match specific positions

Tags: javascript, regex

I've created a regex to match particular positions of characters in a string. I've tested it, and it seems to be functioning OK. But I'm just curious if there's a better way to make this regex better. I appreciate it.

I need a word that have in position:

1: any letter
2: any number
3: any letter
4: have space
5: any number
6: any letter
7: any number

I have written a Regex like this:

```js
/[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z][\s][0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9]/;
```

Comment: This seems more a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient regex for Canadian postal code function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774555/efficient-regex-for-canadian-postal-code-function)

Comment: `/\w\d\w\s\d\w\d/`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:

```
/[a-z]\d[a-z]\s\d[a-z]\d/i
```

- the 'i' flag make the regexp case-insensitive
- \d is equivalent to [0-9]
- and you don't have to put '\s' between square brackets

Comment: This will give false positives, such as with 2+ leading letters, or 2+ digits at the end. You need to anchor the regex, use word boundaries

Comment: @PeterThoeny OP asked only for a simplified version of his regex :)

Answer (score -1):

Your regex looks good, except that you likely want to:

1. anchor the regex at the beginning and end (if you have no adjacent text around it),
2. or use word boundary/expected adjacent chars (if your pattern is within a bigger string)

Also, `\s` includes tab and newline, so you might want to use a simple space   instead.

As for optimization, there is not much you can do, expect for using the `i` flag to ignore case and test for `[a-z]` instead of `[a-zA-Z]`. Also `\d` might be a bit faster than `[0-9]`, not sure (regex implementations are highly optimized.)

Case 1: You have a standalone pattern, e.g. no other text in string

```
/^[a-z]\d[a-z] \d[a-z]\d$/i;
```

Case 2: Your pattern is within a string that has other text

```
/\b[a-z]\d[a-z] \d[a-z]\d\b/i;
```